# truncate table via command line in Linux

Tags: linux, sh, mysql

I want to truncate one of my db table using mysqldump command so that I can place that command in sh file for executing it on daily basis. Do any one know about this command? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use mysql command line client to do it

```
mysql -h dbserver_hostname -e "truncate table schema_name.table_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
localhost=hostname
root=username
''=password
demo=db name
language=table name   

#to truncate a table from database
mysql -h localhost -u root -p'' demo -e "truncate table demo.language"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this working well. Replace vars if you are not using it in a script.

`` mysql -Nse 'show tables' -D $DATABASE -u$USER -p$PWD | while read table; do echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;drop table \`$table\`;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"; done | mysql $DATABASE -u$USER -p$PWD ``