# Truncate tables every 15 minutes Cpanel

Tags: php, sql, cpanel

Can someone help me with how to setup a script (cronjob) in Cpanel to empty tables every 15 minutes?

Thank you in advance

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441994/truncate-table-via-command-line-in-linux and set-up a cron job for the command

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve it.

Using [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html):

```
SET GLOBAL EVENT_SCHEDULER = ON;
  CREATE EVENT truncate some_table_name
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
  DO
  TRUNCATE TABLE 'some_table_name';
```

Using `cron` (if you have access to do it):

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/to/mysql -u[username] -p[password] -d[database_name] -execute="TRUNCATE TABLE `some_table_name`"
```

Comment: Yes i'm using cpanel but what should i type in Command. Sorry i've never used cron jobs before. (see image link)

[Image](http://s8.postimg.org/kvsanbwqt/cronjob.png)

Comment: I'm not sure you have access to run mysql, but nevertheless, try the line form my answer, but write your user name, password and etc. But I think you can also try it to do via MySql

Comment: Okay, but is there no posibility to use a php file in the Command inputfield to import and open every 15 minutes? Because i've 20 tables to empty.

Comment: If you want do truncate tables via php6 you also need to use cron

Comment: Okay, so i can't use this line for example in the command inputfield: /home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php? To add a cronjob.php file and executes a SQL code. Because the line in your answer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add this command to the cron:

```
mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --database=[database_name] --execute="TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name`"
```